# D3.js how to calculate

Tags: d3.js

I have a demo here using D3.js to calculate a total of 100%. How would I do to calculate the total, not 100% but a total of 1000?
When adding up the total of 3 inputs, the total should not be a percentage but a total of 1000.
I'm not familiar with D3.js, I know this should be d3.format but I do not know how to do it.

```js
jQuery($ => {
    $('#submitClick').click(function() {
      var val = parseInt($('#percent').val());
    }).trigger('click');
    
    $(".tags").on('input', function() {
      // needlessly using 2 loops here, amended
      //var calculated_total_sum = $(this).find(".ingredient:checked").map((i, el) => parseFloat($(el).closest("div").find(".txtCal").val())).get().reduce((a, b) => a + b) || 0;   
      var calculated_total_sum = 0;
      $(this).find('div:has(.ingredient:checked) .txtCal').each((i, el) => calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(el.value));   
      
      $("#percent")
        .val(calculated_total_sum)
         .css('color', parseFloat($("#percent").val()) > 1000 ? 'red' : 'green');
        
      drawProgress(calculated_total_sum / 100);
      $("#numberText")
        .val(calculated_total_sum)
        .attr('fill', parseFloat($("#numberText").val()) > 1000 ? 'red' : 'green');
      $("#pathFill")
        .val(calculated_total_sum)
        .attr('fill', parseFloat($("#pathFill").val()) > 1000 ? 'red' : 'green');
        
    });
    
    // ingrédients allergènes
    $('div.tags').on('change', 'input:checkbox', function() {
      $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, 2).hide().val('0');
      var list = $('.results > li').hide();
      
      $('input:checked').each(function() {
        list.filter('.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
        $(this).parent().nextAll().slice(0, 2).show();
      });
    }).find('input:checkbox').change();
  
    $(".tags").on('input', '.txtCal', function() {
      var calculated_total_sum = 0;
      $(".tags .txtCal").each(function() {
        var get_textbox_value = $(this).val();
        if ($.isNumeric(get_textbox_value)) {
          calculated_total_sum += parseFloat(get_textbox_value);
        }
      });
      $("#percent").val(calculated_total_sum);
    });
  
    var svg;
  
    function drawProgress(end) {
      d3.select("svg#ingCircle").remove()
      if (svg) {
        svg.selectAll("*").remove();
      }
      var wrapper = document.getElementById('radialprogress');
      var start = 0;
  
      var colours = {
        fill: 'green',
        track: '#555555',
        text: '#00C0FF',
        stroke: '#FFFFFF',
      }
  
      var radius = 80;
      var border = 12;
      var strokeSpacing = 4;
      var endAngle = Math.PI * 2;
      var formatText = d3.format('.0%');
      var boxSize = radius * 2;
      var count = end;
      var progress = start;
      var step = end < start ? -0.01 : 0.01;
  
      //Define the circle
      var circle = d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(0)
        .innerRadius(radius)
        .outerRadius(radius - border);
  
      //setup SVG wrapper
      svg = d3.select(wrapper)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', boxSize)
        .attr('id', 'ingCircle')
        .attr('height', boxSize);
  
  
      // ADD Group container
      var g = svg.append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + boxSize / 2 + ',' + boxSize / 2 + ')');
  
      //Setup track
      var track = g.append('g').attr('class', 'radial-progress');
      track.append('path')
        .attr('fill', colours.track)
        .attr('stroke', colours.stroke)
        .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px')
        .attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle));
  
      //Add colour fill
      var value = track.append('path')
        .attr('id', 'pathFill')
        .attr('fill', colours.fill)
        .attr('stroke', colours.stroke)
        .attr('stroke-width', strokeSpacing + 'px');
  
      //Add text value
      var numberText = track.append('text')
        .attr('id', 'numberText')
        .attr('fill', colours.text)
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
        .attr('dy', '.5rem');
  
      //update position of endAngle
      value.attr('d', circle.endAngle(endAngle * end));
      //update text value
      numberText.text(formatText(end));
    }
  });
```

```css
.ing-cont{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    height: 16em;
    min-height: 16em;
}
.ing-cont img{
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}
.ing-cont label{
    width: 65%;
    float: left;
}
.txtCal{
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0;
    clear: both;
}
.results{
    list-style: none !important;

}
ul.results li {
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
    padding: .5em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    margin-right: .5em;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
.tags div{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags">
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-1" class="ingredient"> ingredient 1 </label><br><input type="number" class='txtCal' min="0" max="1000" /><br>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-2" class="ingredient"> ingredient 2 </label><br><input type="number" class='txtCal' min="0" max="1000" /><br>
  </div>
  
<div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" checked rel="ingredient-3" class="ingredient"> ingredient 3 </label><br><input type="number" class='txtCal' min="0" max="1000" /><br>
  </div>

  <div id="radialprogress"></div>
<ul class="results">
  <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-3">Alpha isomethylionone</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1">Amyl cinnamal (Jasmonal A)</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1">Amylcinnamyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1">Anisyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-2">Benzyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-1 ingredient-2 ingredient-3">Benzyl benzoate</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2">Benzyl cinnamate</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2">Benzyl salicylate</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2">Butylphenyl methylpropional (Lilial)</li>
  <li class="ingredient-2 ingredient-3">Cinnamal</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Cinnamyl alcohol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Citral</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Citronellol</li>
  <li class="ingredient-3">Coumarin</li>
</ul>

 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. Can you provide an example of data used for calculation and the result you want to achieve?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky sorry if it wasn't clear.
case example: If ingredient 1 = 500 ingredient 2 = 500 ingredient 3 = 0 result should be not 1000% but just 1000 without the % and circle should fill accordingly